# Adding elements (div) to Slider vertically (tiling them)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm looking for the some hacky way to add elements to slider vertically.
Here is the live demo on [JSFiddle](http://bit.ly/1vfM6Y1)

I would like that next sibling after second will take a place below the first element and so on (tiling). Can't figure out what should I add/change.

Comment: so you want the next slide to be partially visible during current slide?

Comment: @SamiaRuponti I want two elements from next slide were below two elements from the first one.

Comment: Like that? http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/qwy6jhy4/31/

Comment: @MrUpsidown damn straight! Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @MrUpsidown sorry didn't mentioned someting. Each div/img/span element should be inside .img-container div.

Comment: Then wrap them in another DIV: http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/qwy6jhy4/32/